# Closure of $\{(x,y) \mid x \neq 0 \ \text{and}\ y \leq \frac{1}{x}\}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $$F = \{(x,y) \mid x \neq 0 \ \text{and}\ y \leq \frac{1}{x}\}$$ I want to find the closure of $F$.

My attempt:

We will prove that $\overline{F} = \{(x,y) \mid xy \leq 1\}$. We see that $\{(x,y) \mid xy \leq 1\} = f^{-1}((-\infty, 1])$, hence it is a closed set, and it implies that  $\overline{F} \subset \{(x,y) \mid xy \leq 1\}$.

Now we will prove the converse inclusion. Consider the cases:

$\textbf{Case 1:}$ We will prove if $x\in \mathbb{R} \ \text{and}\ r>0$, then $B_d((x,0),r) \cap F \neq \emptyset$.

If $x =0$, then $(0, \frac{r}{2}) \in B_d((0,0),r)$.

If $x \neq 0$,  choose $y^\prime = \text{min } \{\frac{1}{2x}, \frac{r}{2}\}$, then $(x, y^\prime) \in B_d((x,0), r) \cap F$ because $$xy^\prime \leq x \cdot \frac{1}{2x} = \frac{1}{2} \leq 1$$
Hence, $(x,0) \in \overline{F}$.

$\textbf{Case 2:}$ We will prove  if $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $r>0$, then $B_d((0,y), r) \cap F \neq \emptyset$.

If $y=0$, then $(\frac{r}{2}, 0) \in B_d((0,0), r)$.

If $y \neq 0$, choose $x^\prime = \text{min } \{\frac{1}{2y}, \frac{r}{2}\}$, then $(x^\prime, y) \in B_d((0,y), r) \cap F$ because $$x^\prime y \leq \frac{1}{2y} \cdot y =\frac{1}{2} \leq 1$$ Hence, $(0, y) \in \overline{F}$.

Now I can not proceed further. Please help me.

Comment: The inequality $y\leq\frac{1}{x}$ is different from $xy\leq 1$, especially when $x$ is negative.

Comment: As pointed above, your region is not correct. (In fact, your proposed closure doesn't contain the original set. Consider the point $(-1, -2)$.) Try drawing a picture. I claim that adding a line to the set will give you the closure. Do you see which line?

Answer (score 1):

The comment was right, your candidate for the closure is too big. (It is indeed a closed set, however, it is not the closure of your original set. And it actually doesn't even contain it)

The good thing is, since your set $\{x \ne 0, y \leq \dfrac{1}{x}\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, you can graph it very easily:[image]

Now, you can see that to "make this set closed", you have to add every limit point that's not in it already. That's gonna be the $y-$axis.

However, the set $\{xy \leq 1\}$ is the following:

[image]

Which is indeed not the right closure.

So what you want to prove is that your closure is the set $E := F \cup \{x = 0\}$.

Now, an exercise is to prove that this set is closed (if you need some hint on that, let me know :)). But once you've done that, all you actually need to prove is that:

- whatever the closure $\bar{F}$ is, it has contain $E$

Cause then, if that holds, then that means $\bar{F} = E$ (since you know that $E$ is closed, and $\bar{F}$ is by definition the smallest closed set containing $F$).

So, to prove that, all you need to show is that every point in $E$ is a limit point of $F$ (which will imply $E \subseteq \bar{F}$). Visually, this should be clear from looking at the picture of the set $F$. But I can go into more details if you'd like :)

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I have written an answer below, as you advised me. Please check and advise me further.

Comment: Hi, I have understood that .... 1. To prove $E$ is closed  we have to show $\mathbb{R}^2 - E$ is open.    2. Clearly, $E$ contains $F$.  3. Can you please advise me how to show $E \subset \overline{F}$?

Comment: Well, $E = F\cup\{x = 0\}$. Every point in $F$ is in $\bar{F}$, so all you need to show is that every point on the line $x = 0$ is a limit point of $F$. In other words, any neighbourhood of such a point will intersect $F$ (which is clear from the picture, if you pick a point on the $y$-axis and some ball around it, it's gonna intersect the pink area)

Answer (score 1):

Our claim is $\overline{F} = F \cup (\{0\} \times \mathbb{R})$.

Take the map $f(x,y) = xy$. Then $f$ is continuous. Thus $F = f^{-1}((-\infty, 0])$, hence is closed. Thus $F \cup (\{0\} \times \mathbb{R})$ is also closed being a product of two closed sets. Now our proposed set clearly contain $F$, hence $\overline{F} \subset F \cup (\{0\} \times \mathbb{R})$.

For the converse inclusion we want to show that every point of $F \cup (\{0\} \times \mathbb{R})$ has a neighborhood that intersects $F$.

The point $(0,0) \in \overline{F}$ because $(0, \frac{r}{2}) \in B_r((0,0),r) \cap F$

If $(0, y)$ be a point such that $y \neq 0$ then choose $x^\prime = \text{min } \{\frac{r}{2}, \frac{1}{y}\}$, then $(x^\prime, y) \in B_d((0,y),r) \cap F$, therefore $(0,y) \in \overline{F}$.

Consider the set $\{(x,y) \mid y>\frac{1}{x}\}$ which is same as $f^{-1}((1, +\infty))$, hence it is an open set contained in $F^c$, therefore a subset of $\text{Int } F^c$, therefore $(x,y) \not\in \overline{F}$.

Hence done.

Comment: Well, $F = \{x \ne 0, y \leq \dfrac{1}{x}\}$, so this is different from $f^{-1}((-\infty, 0]) = \{xy \leq 0\}$. Because that would imply that $F$ is closed, which is not true, else F would be its own closure. To prove closure of $E = F\cup\{x = 0\}$, I guess you could pick some point $p \notin E$ (so $x_p \ne 0$, $y_p > \dfrac{1}{x_p}$). By continuity of the map $x \mapsto 1/x$, you can find a small neighbourhood such that the condition still holds. If necessary, you can make it smaller so that the first condition holds.

Comment: Wait, the LaTeX doesn't display for me, can you see my comment properly?

Comment: @Azur Yes I can see your comment properly.

Comment: Edit: I should have said "continuity of $(x,y) \mapsto y - \dfrac{1}{x}$ instead of the continuity of $x \mapsto 1/x$

Comment: No, my bad, I should have explained in more details. I'm using the fact that $E$ is closed if its complement is open. So I'm taking a point $p$ outside $E$, and showing that we can find a neighbourhood of that point which does not intersect E. Which means $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash E$ is open